# ArrayList and comparing objects in the list to remove

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` called `contains`. It contains objects with many properties like id number, size and priority. After enough objects are inserted to this `ArrayList`, I want to delete the object with the highest priority from the `ArrayList`.

But the problem is I can't do this by index. I can't simply say `contains.remove(index I know has highest priority)` because the indexes will change and I wont be able to keep track of what they change to. I need a loop or something to look through the array list and remove the specific object in it with the highest priority.

So is there a way to look through the objects in an `ArrayList`, the objects in this case are tasks, and remove from the `ArrayList` the object with the highest priority?

Comment: Loop over the elements in the list, check whether its priority is higher than the highest already encountered priority. If it  is, store its index. Once you have looped through the entire list, delete the element with the stored index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you actually need `TreeSet`, but not `ArrayList`.

1. Either make you objects `Comparable`, or create a `Comparator` for them. Base your comparison logic on `priority` property.
2. Store your objects in `TreeSet`.
3. When you need to delete an object with highest priority, use `pollFirst()/pollLast()`.

Besides that, check `PriorityQueue`, maybe it will suite you even better.

The main idea is to use data structure that supports ordering from the box, basing on yours comparison implementation. It will save you from writing loops and make your "remove with highest priority" operation much faster: O(logN) (`TreeSet`) or even O(1) (`PriorityQueue`), instead of O(N) (manual iteration through `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way would be to iterate over all entries and save the one with the highest priority, then remove it.

A better idea would be to keep the list sorted so you only need to remove the first / last element.